# Get a JQuery promise using Algolia Instantsearch.js library

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred, algolia

I'm using the instantsearch.js library to manage my result from Algolia API.

I would like to know if there is a way to get a promise with instantsearch.js ?

I'm currently using the command :

```
search.on('render', function() {
    // code
});
```

to execute my code but I would like to wait for other ajax asynchronous results before process my code.

My purpose is to get something like following :

```
var request1 = $.ajax( url );

var request2 = $.ajax( url );

var result = search.on('render', function() {
    // code
}

$.when(request1, request2, result).then(
    function(){
        console.log("success", arguments);
    },
    function(){
        console.log("fail", arguments);
    });
```

Is anyone have a solution ?

Thanks a lot.

Sam

Comment: Event functions are meant to be called many times, there will be several values. On the other hand, promises represent an eventual single value. I think there is a fundamental mismatch here, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to promisify the "rendered" event is :

```
var request1 = $.ajax(url);
var request2 = $.ajax(url);
var rendered = $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
    search.on('render', dfrd.resolve);
});

$.when(request1, request2, rendered).then(function(result1, result2) {
    console.log(result1, result2);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Although it's not a big deal here, deferreds/promises are rather expensive in terms of performance. You will get the same effect less expensively with :

```
var request1 = $.ajax(url);
var request2 = $.ajax(url);
search.on('render', function() {
    $.when(request1, request2).then(function(result1, result2) {
        console.log(result1, result2);
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't resolve twice a promise so this won't work when using events. Maybe you could use `once` instead of `on`.

Comment: @bobylito, the 'render' event will only ever fire once so `.on()` and `.once()` will have identical effect.

Comment: That's correct! I misread the name of the event in the first place :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create a deferred object, resolve or reject deferred object at `render` event handler

```
var request1 = $.ajax( url );

var request2 = $.ajax( url );

var result = new $.Deferred();

search.on('render', function() {
    // code
    result.resolve(/* value */);
})

$.when(request1, request2, result)
.then(
    function() {
        console.log("success", arguments);
    },
    function() {
        console.log("fail", arguments);
});
```